# How to check and pipe unique email fields in NestJs and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, error-handling, nestjs

I need to validate the email to fix the `E11000` error before sending a query in nestjs mongoose.

**1. Controller**

```
 @Post('register')
  async register(@Body() register: RegisterDto) {
    return this.authService.register(register);
  }
```

**2. Data Type**

```
import { IsEmail, IsNotEmpty, IsString } from 'class-validator';

export class RegisterDto {
...
  /* I wish to add some code here with Validate() */
  /* such as @Validate(UserExistsRule) */
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;
...
}
```

**3. main.ts**

```
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';

async function bootstrap() {
...
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
...
}
```

**4. Schema**

```
@Prop({ required: true, index: true, unique: true })
email: string;
```

The issue is I have to handle duplicate errors when there is an email address already on MongoDB.

If you know how to handle custom validation with unique fields in Nest.Js pipe and Mongoose, Could you write here?

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Hopefully, I wish to add validation before trying to register a new Document. Without handling the below error:

```
ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] E11000 duplicate key error collection: nnm-starter.users index: email_1 dup key: { email: "email@email.com" }
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: Generally, you catch the `E11000 duplicate key error` and handle it. This is a MongoDB Server error (an instance of `MongoServerError`) thrown when the Unique Constraint (created via a Unique Index) is violated. This error has a `code` with value `11000`.

Comment: Yes, I did it on several projects. But I thought I can do it in smart way with Nest.Js pipe. https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes

Comment: You can validate for the uniqueness only by accessing the data from the database. I see that you can read the database and verify if the field/value already exists (and then do the  insert) - this would be two calls to the database. The other option is to catch and handle the E11000 error.

Comment: But I think it is a better way to use validate query before all. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.validate/

Comment: Additionally, how are you going to use `db.collection.validate` in your use case?

Comment: Yes, exactly with nestjs pipe